# Scss nuxt: sass expected "{" error when no style tag in file

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

If I for example have this in my /pages/settings.vue:

```js
<template>
  ...
</template>
```

or

```js
<template>
  ...
</template>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

I get the error (inside template can be anything):

```
[plugin:vite:css] [sass] expected "{".
  ╷
3 │ </template>
  │            ^
  ╵
  pages\settings.vue 3:12  root stylesheet
```

but as soon as I add a style tag with any content (any css language and the content can even be a comment) to the file the error vanishes.

```js
<template>
  ...
</template>

<style lang="scss">
/* error if this is not here idk why */
</style>
```

how can I prevent that because some pages do not have any styles?

I tried:

- changed content in
- other files
- reinstalling sass package

Comment: Which version of nuxt are you using? Do you have any config that inject style (in nuxt.config, a library...)?

Comment: @Kapcash nuxt v3, modules: ["@nuxtjs/supabase"], injections vite: { css: { preprocessorOptions: { scss: { additionalData: '@use "~/assets/styles/_colors.scss" as *;' } } } },